# How to use ffplay visualizations in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

I want to play audio using the ffplay to view different displays for example aphasemeter but without having to encode in ffmpeg. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

e.g.

```
ffplay -vf aphasemeter in.mp3
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38105069/5726027 for a more comprehensive visualization output.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem to the use amovie = c: \full\path\to\file apparently a solution is use amovie = c\\: / full / path / to / file. the idea is convert the path in it of the solution through a bath file? without need of modifying it manually

Comment: Yes, within the filtergraph, you have to escape the \ and : characters. Not if you enter them as a main argument e.g. `ffplay -af aphasemeter c:\path\to\file.mp3`